# Feynman diagrams in statistical physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, feynman-diagrams

Feynman diagrams were, to my understanding, first developed in QED to calculate things such as scattering amplitudes and the running of the coupling constants.
They have later been adopted to condensed matter and statistical physics.
However, the only application of Feynman diagrams I have seen in statistical physics are to calculate the renormalization group equations and from these the critical exponents.
Examples are the $ O(N) $ Model, the KPZ and the Toner and Tu equations.

Are there other uses of Feynman diagrams in statistical physics?
Can other (useful) physical observables be computed, and if so, what are the examples of these?

Edit: To be more specific, I am curious about *classical, statistical* models.

Answer (score 5):

Using Feynmann diagrams for the Rennormalization group calculations is a relatively recent development. They have been extensively used in the context of Feynmann-Dyson expansion of quantities of interest for quite a long time - AGD's [*Methods of Quantum Field Theory in Statistical Physics*](https://www.amazon.fr/Methods-Quantum-Theory-Statistical-Physics/dp/0486632288) is the classical text here, but see also Fetter&Walecka's [*Quantum Theory of Many-Particle Systems*](https://www.amazon.fr/Quantum-Theory-Many-Particle-Systems-Alexander/dp/0070206538) for a more pedestrian approach.

More recent applications incorporate Keldysh approach to adapt the diagrams for non-equilibrium processes, relevant in the solid state. See
[*Quantum field-theoretical methods in transport theory of metals*](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.58.323) by Rammer and Smith and [*Quantum Kinetics in Transport and Optics of Semiconductors*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-73564-9) by Haug and Jauho.

The main difference with Feynmann diagrams in QFT is that one calculates averages over a statistical ensemble, rather than the individual processes (scattering matrices). This makes the diagrams somewhat less transparent, as they do not connect the understandable initial and final states in vacuum, but rather some abstract states resulting from "adding and subtracting a particle" to the many-particle system, or even less transparent four-point diagrams (e.g., in Kubo formula calculations.) But mathematically the approach is very similar.

Comment: Thank you. These sources show that Feynman diagrams are used to calculate perturbatively non-critical observables with Feynman diagrams. However, as far as I can see, this is all in quantum models. Are there any examples of such calculations in entirely classical models? That is, are there Feynman diagram calculations for physical observables in classical statistical ensembles, outside RG calculations?

Comment: Cluster expansion in classical stat physics can be formulated in terms of Feynman diagrams. Also perturbative calculations for Ising model. Beyond physics *graphical models* are fashionable in statistics and machine learning. Also graphs are extensively used in algorithms/computer science.